# tortoise.exceptions.ConfigurationError: Unknown DB scheme: postgresql error

Tags: python, fastapi, tortoise-orm

I'm learning tortoise and am trying to configure Postgres with `register_tortoise` looking like below:

```
register_tortoise(
    app,
    db_url="postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/testdb",
    modules={'models': ['db.models.users']},
    generate_schemas=True,
    add_exception_handlers=True
)
```

But I get this error

```
tortoise.exceptions.ConfigurationError: Unknown DB scheme: postgresql

ERROR:    Application startup failed. Exiting.
```

Could someone help me figure out the error?

Comment: The scheme should be `postgres://` not `postgresql://`.

Comment: `postgres://` was the solution for me. Some tools use `postgresql` (databases, sqlalchemy), where as tortoise expects the connection string to start the way you described it. thx